# Take picture using camera2 in android

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

In the days of the "old" camera-API I used the simple code:

```
        Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
        startActivityForResult(imageIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
```

and it worked great.

Now with camera2 the sample code is about 1035 lines of code - [android-camera2Basic example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java).

Isn't there a simpler way of just taking a picture with the new camera2-API ?

Comment: are you using only back camera ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the days of the "old" camera-API I used the simple code:

That code has nothing to do with the "'old' camera-API" (`android.hardware.Camera`).

> Isn't there a simpler way of just taking a picture with the new camera2-API ?

The code in your question works just fine... within [the limits of the camera apps that you might be linking to](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/08/action-image-capture-fallacy.html).

Implementing `android.hardware.Camera` was somewhat easier than `android.hardware.camera2.*`, but not by a lot, and both APIs are terribly complicated.

Comment: Great - thanks! It seems I misunderstood the whole thing - so camera2 is just some more checks for permissions and then using the same code does the same thing

Comment: @Vladimir: No. `android.hardware.Camera` and `android.hardware.camera2.*` are APIs to the camera hardware. You use those to write a camera app. Your code snippet is *linking* to a camera app supplied by somebody else (device manufacturer or user).